# Get User Name by its ID Azure AD

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-sdks

We use Azure AD for authentication and store users' IDs (object IDs) in our API. We need to resolve these IDs into user names. I tried to do it using Microsoft graph and On-Behalf-Of flow to exchange our token to another with the required scope but it is quite complex and requires User.Read.All permissions for users.

So my question is - Is any other approach how to resolving the user Id into a name?

Comment: `use Azure AD for authentication ` then you are able to get user name by `var user = HttpContext.User.Identity;` in the controller.

Comment: This way I can only get the current user's name, but I want to get any user's name by it's ID

Comment: `get any user's name` requires to use client credential flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get any user's name by it's ID ---> then you must give application [api permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) for `User.Read.All, User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.Read.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All`. `Read.All` allows you to get any user's name.

[image]

And then you have to use client credential flow to get authorization and call graph api. I'm afraid On-Behalf-Of is not suitable for you. Try my code below.

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
string tenantId = "TenantId";
string clientId = "ClientId";
string clientSecret = "ClientSecret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
var user = await graphClient.Users["user_id"].Request().GetAsync();
```